# Scroll To Bottom Of Page On Click On Header - Only CSS

Tags: html, css, scroll, css-selectors

I have a header (which is an image) that spans across the entire screen.
I want the page to scroll down (smoothly..) whenever I click on the header, to a different element.

The thing is I'm trying to accomplish this only using CSS, so I could have better smartphone experience.
I've looked at several tutorials but they all seem to work using an external fixed navigation bar.

I noticed there is a new psuedo-class :has() which picks the parent and might be very useful. Is it supported yet by browsers?

Thank you!

Code structure, more or less:

```
<body>
    <img src="foobar.jpg" id="header" /> <!-- Onclick, scroll down to div -->
    <div id="SecondElement">
        All sorts of information
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: just saying smooth scrolling is not available to CSS only. If you can't use JS, you can't change the way the page scrolls.

Comment: What do you mean? Using anchors and animation? Look here: http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/06/12/css-only-responsive-layout-with-smooth-transitions/

Comment: Yeah you didn't make that clear from your question at all. What you said sounded like you wanted to do something like [this](http://jsbin.com/mexipiyiho/1/), where you would be able to define the scrolling, which is impossible like I said. If your question is actually if we could write you the code that made that page, the answer is: sorry we're not an army of programming gnomes, you'll have to come back with an actual question. PS: the `:has` thing you're talking about is [only available in jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/).

Comment: If you're trying to make something that works just like that thing you're linking to, then please go by the instructions you've just linked to.

Comment: First of all, I'd appreciate it if you used kinder language. I apologize, I did not understand the source of your mistake or what you thought I meant. I did not ask anyone to write the entire code, just to give me the basic idea of how it should be done. Secondly, the selector I referred to is implemented in CSS4: http://dev.w3.org/csswg/selectors4/#relational, I just don't know if it's supported yet.

Comment: Even once it's supported, it may not be usable in CSS. See [this section](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/selectors4/#profiles). This can change anytime, of course, but for now, it's tentatively excluded.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question most directly, `:has`, or any of the other css4 features for that matter, are not supported by any browsers yet. The current standard is CSS3, which is only just starting to get wider support from modern browsers. Now, for making the scrolling page, you'll have to use the examples on that page, or if you have a more direct question about something, you can ask it here.

Comment: As I wrote in the question, I did see some tutorials but they aren't helpful as they use an external navigation bar. I want the element that is clicked to be inside the container itself.

Answer (score 0):

**CSS method** Jumps to the DIV with that the id that matches the href. Not smooth.

```
<ul>
 <li><a href="#1">Content 1</a></li>
 <li><a href="#2">Content 2</a></li>
 <ul>

  <div id="1"</div>
  <div id="2"></div>
```

**jQuery method**

```
 $(document).delegate('.your-button', 'click', function () {
        $('body').scrollTo('#target'); // Scroll  to target element
        return false;
    });
```

Comment: I am familiar with basic anchors but I would like to insist on using pure CSS. Thank you for your help.